# C#/.Net Changelog

Tags: c#, .net

I started programming C# applications when the 1.0 framework was first released. I worked professionally with it for about three years right up until just before the 2.0 framework release.

As I look now I see that 3.5 came out last year and that each new version of the framework has added large sets of features that are interconnected.

Is there a good reference (either printed or web) that would catch someone up to the present day situation, given that they already have a firm grounding in .NET?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSDN has a series of "What's new in .." for most of their technologies.

- [What's New in the .NET Framework
  Version 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t357fb32(VS.80).aspx)
- [What's New in the .NET Framework
  Version 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822048.aspx)
- [What's New in the .NET Framework
  Version 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332048.aspx)
- [What's New in the .NET Framework
  Version 3.5 SP1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713697.aspx)
- etc. search google "What's New in XYZ"

And [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2008/10/29/net-framework-4-poster.aspx) is a poster highlighting recent changes. 
Preview:
[image]